# How do you add collision and make my foes to go slower in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I made a game where the player has to dodge things called foes. I have tried doing the collision but have had no luck with it and I am not sure how to get the foes to go slower. The following is what I have so far:

```
import pygame,random, sys
    from pygame.locals import *
    from Player import *
    from Person import *
    from Badies import *
    def terminate():
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    def writeText(window, written, cenX, cenY):
        font = pygame.font.Font(None, 48)
        text = font.render(written, 1, TEXTCOLOR)
        textpos = text.get_rect()
        textpos.centerx = cenX
        textpos.centery = cenY
        window.blit(text, textpos)
        return (textpos)

    def waitForPlayerToPressKey():
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    terminate()
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE: # pressing escape quits
                        terminate()
                    return

    def playerHitFoes(playerRect, foes):
        for f in foes:
            if guy.getRect(f['rect']):
                return True
        return False

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

    pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 1)
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

    WINDOWWIDTH = 800
    WINDOWHEIGHT = 600
    TEXTCOLOR = (255, 255, 255)
    FPS = 40
    BADDIEMAXSIZE = 35
    BADDIEMINSIZE = 35
    BADDIEMAXSPEED = 10
    BADDIEMINSPEED = 10
    ADDNEWFOESRATE = 6
    PLAYERMOVERATE = 5
    changedRecs=[]
    BACKGROUNDCOLOR = (255, 255, 255)
    gameWin = False
    win=False
    score = 0
    windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    guy = Player(400, 525)

    foes = Badies()
    playerRect = getRec(guy)
    foess = pygame.image.load('Bad.png')

    writeText(screen,"How to Play?" , 400,100)
    writeText(screen,"*Help Mario dodge the squares", 400,150) 
    writeText(screen,"*Controls: Up, Down, Left, Right.", 400,200)
    writeText(screen,"(Press Any Key to Start.)", 400,250)
    pygame.display.update()
    waitForPlayerToPressKey()
    gameEnd = foes.drawAndCollision(screen, guy)
    pygame.display.update()
    gameEnd = foes.drawAndCollision(screen, guy)

    WHITE = (255,255,255)
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.display.update()
    while True:
        # set up the start of the game
        foes= []
        score = 0
        moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp = moveDown = False
        r = s = False
        foesAddCounter = 0

        while True: # the game loop runs while the game part is playing
            score += 1 # increase score

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    terminate()

                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_LEFT:
                        guy.moveLeft()
                    if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                        guy.moveRight()
                    if event.key == K_UP:
                        guy.moveUp()
                    if event.key == K_DOWN:
                        guy.moveDown()

            if not r and not s:
                foesAddCounter += 1
            if foesAddCounter == ADDNEWFOESRATE:
                foesAddCounter = 0
                baddieSize = BADDIEMAXSIZE
                newFoes = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-baddieSize), 0 - baddieSize, baddieSize, baddieSize),
                            'speed': BADDIEMAXSPEED,
                            'surface':pygame.transform.scale(foess, (baddieSize, baddieSize)),
                            }


                foes.append(newFoes)


            for f in foes:
                if not r and not s:
                    f['rect'].move_ip(0, f['speed'])
                elif reverseCheat:
                    f['rect'].move_ip(0, -5)
                elif slowCheat:
                    f['rect'].move_ip(0, 1)

            for f in foes[:]:
                if f['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                    foes.remove(f)

            screen.fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)

            writeText(screen,"Score: %s" % (score), 10, 0)

            guy.draw(screen)

            for f in foes:
                windowSurface.blit(f['surface'], f['rect'])

            pygame.display.update()

            if playerHasHitBaddie(playerRect, baddies):
                writeText(screen, "Game Over!", 400,300)
                break




        pygame.display.update()

    This next part is the Player File:
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *

    class Player:
        # set all class variables in the constructor
        def __init__(self, newX, newY):
            self.x = newX
            self.y = newY

            # Add images to the list of images
            self.images = [ "Player.gif", "PlayerR.gif","PlayerR.gif", "Player.gif"]

            # Use this to keep track of which image to use
            self.cos = 0

        #  draw your person with the correct image
        def draw(self, window):
            window.blit( pygame.image.load( self.images[ self.cos ]   ),
                         (self.x,self.y))

        # move person left and set the costume facing left.
        def moveLeft(self):
            self.x -= 1
            self.cos = 3

        # move person right and set the costume facing right
        def moveRight(self):
            self.x += 1
            self.cos = 2

        # move person up and set the costume facing up
        def moveUp(self):
            self.y -= 1
            self.cos = 1

        # move person down and set the costume facing down
        def moveDown(self):
            self.y += 1
            self.cos = 0


        def playerHitFoes(playerRect, foes):
            for f in foes:
                if playerRect.colliderect(f['rect']):
                    return True
        def playerHasHitHeart(playerRect, foes):
            for h in heart:
                if playerRect.colliderect(h['rect']):
                    return True

        def collide(self, other):
            myRec = self.getRec
            otherRec = other.getRec()
            oRight  = otherRec[0] + otherRec[2]
            oBottom  = otherRec[1] + otherRec[3]

            right = myRec[0] + myRec[2]
            bottom = myRec[1] + myRec[3]


            if (otherRec[0] <= right) and (oRight >= self.x) and (otherRec[1] <= bottom) and (oBottom >= self.y):
                return True
            return False
    def getRec(self):
        myRec = pygame.image.load( self.images[ self.cos ]   ).get_rect()
        return (self.x, self.y, myRec[2], myRec[3])
```

Comment: `if playerRect.colliderect(f['rect']):` should be `if playerRect.colliderect(f['rect'].rect):` - Unless pygame does redicilous assumptions and magic for you, you need to insert a `pygame.Rect()` object into `colliderect(<Rect()>)` for it to be happy. - See more [here](http://pygame.org/project-Rect+Collision+Response-1061-.html)

Comment: Also your identation is wonky, `This next part is the Player File:` for instance, is a slight hint that there's a indentation issue when you pasted your code, please correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Without having access to the gif's and being able to run this code, I'm going to assume your problem lies within how you check for collisions.

Namely, the `colliderect()` function takes one parameter, and it should be a `pygame.Rect()` object.

Meaning when you do your `playerHitFoes` you should pass the `.rect` object of your `f['rect']` objects like so:

```
def playerHitFoes(playerRect, foes):
    for f in foes:
        if playerRect.colliderect(f['rect'].rect):
            return True
def playerHasHitHeart(playerRect, foes):
    for h in heart:
        if playerRect.colliderect(h['rect'].rect):
            return True
```

This might or might not solve your issue.
But I'll touch on some other things I found that is most likely not crucial to this problem, but might give you problems down the line.

```
def playerHitFoes(playerRect, foes):
    for f in foes:
        if guy.getRect(f['rect']):
            return True
    return False
```

In the code above, `playerRect` is never used, `guy` is not defined (all tho it will most likely pull the `guy = Player()` just fine, but this might cause issues for you.

`playerHitFoes()` is also defined twice, once out in the wild and once in the player function. But it's never used in your code examples.

`playerHitFoes`, `playerHasHitHeart` and `collide?` is never called upon anywhere in your code.

`playerHasHitBaddie` is used to check if `game is over`, but `playerHasHitBaddie` is never defined.

**This code would give a lot of exceptions** even if i had the gifs.
So I'll assume this is just a minor part of your code and you left out a lot of things.. So either the above solves the problem - or you need to give at least me more detail.. For instance what code do you use to do the actual collision detection?

### List of things not defined or not used

- `Badies()` - We don't know what it looks like
- `foes.drawAndCollision`
- `playerHasHitBaddie`
- `playerHitFoes`
- `playerHasHitHeart`
- `collide`
- `gameWin`
- `changedRecs`
- `PLAYERMOVERATE`
- `BADDIEMINSPEED`
- `BADDIEMINSIZE`
- `FPS`
- `win`
- `guy`, `TEXTCOLOR` (Local variables in functions assuming global presence)

This was just to name a few.
One important one is what `Badies()` look like and how check/call for the collision detection.